# A typeparam property set unexpectedly to null after changing Value of another typeparam

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, null, blazor

**Note:** this seems to be a bug.

Version: Blazor WebAssembly v5.0

**Short explanation** : I have two `typeparam`(s) `TValue` for the `Value` and `TItem` for `SelectedItem` from a list of `TItem`(s). When I set the `TValue Value`( after `ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value)`) the `TItem SelectedItem` which has nothing to do with `Value` will be set to `null`. When I look at stack-frame it(the set method) will be called by Blazor JavaScript files so it was not helpful.

Actually I was creating an autocomplete component but I can not provide the actual code that make sense but I created a test component that may not make sense in terms of what it should do but can demonstrate the problem.

Here is the whole code of the `ATestComponent`

```
@typeparam TValue
@typeparam TItem

ATestComponent ***
@if(SelectedItem!=null)
{
    <P>this is just to show SelectedItem, 
         but the SelectedItem became null unexpectedly after
         Value is being changed .
         SelectedItem = @DisplayMember(SelectedItem)
    </P>
}
<InputNumber @bind-Value="@Value"></InputNumber>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <li @onclick="@(() => itemClicked(item))" style="background-color:cyan">@DisplayMember(item)</li>
    }
</ul>

***
@code {


    [Parameter] public Func<TItem, object> ValueMember { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Func<TItem, string> DisplayMember { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Items { get; set; } = null;

    [Parameter] public TItem? SelectedItem { get; set; } = default(TItem);


    private TValue? _value;
    [Parameter]
    public TValue? Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            var hasChanged = !EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(value, Value);

            if (hasChanged)
            {
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
                // unexpectedly after this line the SelectedItem will set to null !
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    public void itemClicked(TItem item)
    {
        SelectedItem = item;
        Value = (TValue)ValueMember(item);
    }

}
```

and this is how I use it  :

```
<ATestComponent @bind-Value="@entity.ProvinceId" 
                                        DisplayMember="@(a => a.Name)" 
                                        ValueMember="@(a => a.Id)" 
                                        SelectedItem="@entity.Province" 
                                        Items="@ProvinceItems"
                                        TItem="Province"
                                        TValue="int?"
                                        ></ATestComponent>

// in which @entity is of type City and @ProvinceItems is of type List<Province>
```

**Explanation:**

1. There is a `p` element to show `TItem SelectedItem`.
2. There is an `input` to hold the `TValue Value`.
3. There is an `ul` to select the `SelectedItem` and set the `Value`.

**Expected Behavior :** Suppose this is a `Province` selector for a `City`. When I click on each `li` the `input` should set to the `Id` of the corresponding `Province` and the `P` element should become rendered(as `SelectedItem` is not null anymore) and show the text containing the `Name`(`DisplayMember`) of corresponding `Province`.

**Current Behavior(buggy!)**:

- When I click on a `li` the `input` will change correctly all the
  times.
- When I click any `li` for the first time the `SelectedItem` will get
  a value but unexpectedly after executing the `set` method of `Value`
  property, the `SelectedItem` `set` method will be called with a null
  value by an unknown caller (from Blazor js).
- If I click the same `li` two times in a row because the `if (hasChanged)` block is not executed the SelectedItem will not get a
  null value and the P element will be shown with desired value. In
  other words **when the `if (hasChanged)` block is called which has
  nothing to do with SelectedItem, the SelectedItem set to null**.
- If I click any `li` different from the perivous click the `P` element will not rendered as the `if (hasChanged)` has been executed

Comment: Is your `InputNumber` wrapped in an `EditForm`? Also, it would be much more helpful if you include the definition of your `City` and `Provice` class for more context.

Comment: @AmalK yes it is .  City {Id, Name, ProvinceId , Province}  , Province{ Id ,Name }

Comment: Very easy to blame Blazor for any bug you've got in your code and knowledge. The correct answer has already been given to you by @Mister Magoo.

Comment: @enet if this is what is intended why not the Value itself get re-initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set `[Parameter]` values inside the component - they are public parameters that Blazor controls and sets.

If you change the value of `SelectedItem` within the component, Blazor cannot track that change.

When you raise the `ValueChanged` `EventCallback` it will re-render the parent (and this component as a child of the parent) and that process will set the public `[Parameter]` `SelectedItem` to `@entity.Province`, which presumably is  `null`.

Some of the time this will appear to work just fine, but it is not always going to be fine, so don't rely on it.

So, to avoid this problem, you could track the SelectedItem using a private variable inside the component, using the public Parameter only to set the initial value.

Comment: the SelectedItem should be changed both from outside and inside of the components multiple times not just for initialization. any comments on how to achieve that ?

Comment: Use a local variable inside, and either use SetParametersAsync or a custom setter on SelectedItem to update the local variable. Just don't update SelectedItem inside the component as it will not propagate back to the parent. Edit: got wrong method in 1st sentence.

Comment: Of course how you decide when to allow the value of SelectedItem to override the local value can become difficult. If you need to track the SelectedItem in the parent, then you will need another callback so the child can tell the parent it has changed SelectedItem.

Comment: the answer works but in order to see if it's a bug or not I don't it as the answer FOR A WHILE.

Comment: SetParametersAsync  will run every time ValueChanged executed so it will re-init the SelectedItem and it causes the other private property to reset again :(

Comment: That's the point of my last comment - you have to have an idea of when to allow the parameter to override...